# How to pivot a table this way when there are 3000 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server

I have a table TT that looks like this

```
TargetID    RowID   Actual
0001        1         0
0001        2         1
0001        3         1
0002        1         0
0002        2         1
0002        3         0
0003        1         1
0003        2         1
0003        3         0
```

How can I pivot it is to this

```
RowID     Target0001     Target0002     Target0003
1            0              0               1
2            1              1               1
3            1              0               0
```

I tried

```
SELECT 'TargetID' + TargetID, RowID, Actual
FROM TT 
WHERE TargetID = '0001'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TargetID' + TargetID, RowID, Actual
FROM TT 
WHERE TargetID = '0002'
SELECT 'TargetID' + TargetID, RowID, Actual
FROM TT 
WHERE TargetID = '0003'
```

But there are 3000 TargetIDs and my method is not good for that

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have you read the [PIVOT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) yet? I expect you are going to hit the limit of [1,024 columns per table/view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#-objects), though.

Comment: Is there a hard requirement to do this in SQL? A pivot table tool (or even just Microsoft Excel) seems a better choice.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker yes it has to be in SQL

Comment: 3000 columns might be overkill: how would you even view that many columns?

Comment: @Charlieface it is for academic research.

Comment: I didn't ask you what it was for, I asked you how you would view it, what would you use to view so many columns? Really this is much better done in the presentation layer rather than in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
DECLARE @ColumnsTable TABLE ([ColumnName] VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @ColumnsTable ([ColumnName])
SELECT  DISTINCT  '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(48), [TargetID]) + ']'
FROM   TT;

DECLARE @PivotColumns VARCHAR(MAX), @TotalColumn VARCHAR(MAX), @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @PivotColumns = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [ColumnName])
                                   FROM   @ColumnsTable
                                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''));
SET @SQL = 'SELECT RowID,' +@PivotColumns +'
FROM   (
SELECT  RowID,TargetID,Actual                
        FROM   TT) AS t 
       PIVOT (MAX([Actual])
             FOR [TargetID] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS p';
EXEC(@SQL);
```